# What is the effect on browser performance when the (X)HTML is invalid

Tags: html, browser, xhtml, performance, xml-validation

When a given (X)Html document doesn't conform to the specified doctype, what is the performance hit on the browser?

Comment: That's going to vary between browsers. As such this question is too vague. I'm voting to close. Your best approach would be to test this yourself.

Comment: I don't think it would be.  Considering how long browsers have been around for, there must be some general consensus on what the performance hit is/may be, even if that's just for Firefox and IE.

Furthermore, getting the accurate numbers would require very detailed testing of the rendering algorithms in play - something that is rather beyond my capabilities.

Comment: The general wisdom on this front would be, don't measure the browser's HTML fixing powers... fix your HTML instead!

Comment: Maybe the content is pulled from a source which the author has no control and a decision is to be made if they should try to fix it before sending it to the client with server side code or leave this task for the browsers?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, negligible. However, there are some cases that are invalid because of their disproportionally poor performance, see [the standard](http://www.whatwg.org/html/#syntax-errors).

Also, some error handling in quirks mode may affect performance. For example, [until Firefox 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_5_for_developers), Firefox had some rather involved error handling related to image maps, which was limited to quirks mode. Of course, this doesn't depend on complying to any particular specification, but depends on the doctype used. As usual, I suggest using `<!doctype html>` for the safest, most standards-compliant, and, indeed, fastest handling of your web sites.

Comment: Someone from Mozilla, or possibly Chrome, wrote about this same thing and stated much the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the performance hit would be negligible, however the page may look wrong.

Comment: No award for stating the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser has its own implementation when it comes to correcting broken (x)html. But even our open source glory Firefox [had its problems](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=148562) when trying to fix broken html and some complex code will cause noticeable lag on page load. It may be preferable if you need to pass dynamic (but broken) html generated by a 3rd party service to the client, rather than trying to fix it for each request. But, if the content is static or can be cached for a period on the server, fixing it will grant higher SEO, faster page loads, happier visitors.

By the way, apart from extreme cases, [we already live in a world of malformed html](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/11/its-a-malformed-world.html)